# How can you modify edge weights for a filtered Petgraph graph?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, petgraph

I am using an edge filter for my graph and want to update an edge weight:

```rust
use petgraph::prelude::*;
use petgraph::graph;
use petgraph::visit::{Dfs, EdgeFiltered, IntoEdges};

fn filter_edges(edge: graph::EdgeReference<u32>) -> bool {
    match edge.weight() {
        0 => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut graph: graph::Graph<u32, u32> = graph::Graph::new();
    let a = graph.add_node(1);
    let b = graph.add_node(2);
    let e = graph.add_edge(a, b, 0);
    let mut filtered_graph = EdgeFiltered::from_fn(&graph, filter_edges);
    let mut dfs = Dfs::new(&filtered_graph, a);
    while let Some(node_index) = dfs.next(&filtered_graph) {
        for edge in filtered_graph.edges(node_index) {
            filtered_graph.update_edge(edge.source(), edge.target(), 1);
            //graph.update_edge(edge.source(), edge.target(), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

But this errors because `EdgeFiltered` doesn't have an `update_edge` function:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `update_edge` found for struct `EdgeFiltered<&Graph<u32, u32>, for<'r> fn(petgraph::graph::EdgeReference<'r, u32>) -> bool {filter_edges}>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:22:28
   |
22 |             filtered_graph.update_edge(edge.source(), edge.target(), 1);
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `EdgeFiltered<&Graph<u32, u32>, for<'r> fn(petgraph::graph::EdgeReference<'r, u32>) -> bool {filter_edges}>`
```

If I switch to refer to the original `graph` instead, it has a borrow checker error (unlike `Dfs`, unfortunately `EdgeFiltered` isn't designed to let you access the original graph):

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `graph` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:21:13
   |
17 |     let mut filtered_graph = EdgeFiltered::from_fn(&graph, filter_edges);
   |                                                    ------ immutable borrow occurs here
18 |     let mut dfs = Dfs::new(&filtered_graph, a);
19 |     while let Some(node_index) = dfs.next(&filtered_graph) {
   |                                           --------------- immutable borrow later used here
20 |         for edge in filtered_graph.edges(node_index) {
21 |             graph.update_edge(edge.source(), edge.target(), 1);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

[Playground link for the above](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd90dd40b748c29eee2bd2c5f7a8ee2b)

`Edgefiltered` is pretty minimal, and doesn't really seem to have anything intended for mutable graph manipulation. Is there any way to do this with what Petgraph comes with, or will I have to write my own version of `update_edge` showhow?

Comment: If there's no better way, I'll probably make a vec of edge IDs, fill it out during traversal, and then modify the edges later on.

Answer (score 1):

`FilteredGraph` borrows the `Graph`, therefore you cannot get a mutable reference to the `Graph` as long as `FilteredGraph` exists.

You can re-create a `FilteredGraph` on each `dfs.next()` call to work around this, e.g. this works:

```
use petgraph::graph;
use petgraph::visit::{Dfs, EdgeFiltered};

fn filter_edges(edge: graph::EdgeReference<u32>) -> bool {
    match edge.weight() {
        0 => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut graph: graph::Graph<u32, u32> = graph::Graph::new();
    let a = graph.add_node(1);
    let b = graph.add_node(2);
    let e = graph.add_edge(a, b, 0);
    let filtered_graph = EdgeFiltered::from_fn(&graph, filter_edges);
    let mut dfs = Dfs::new(&filtered_graph, a);
    while let Some(node_index) = dfs.next(&EdgeFiltered::from_fn(&graph, filter_edges)) {
        let mut neighbors = graph.neighbors(node_index).detach();
        while let Some((edge_idx, _)) = neighbors.next(&graph) {
            graph[edge_idx] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:* This will take the neighbors of the given node based on the edges present in `graph`, not by those present in `filtered_graph`.

You can solve that by ditching `EdgeFiltered` and manually handling it in the traversal, e.g. like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut graph: graph::Graph<u32, u32> = graph::Graph::new();
    let a = graph.add_node(1);
    let b = graph.add_node(2);
    let e = graph.add_edge(a, b, 0);
    let mut dfs = Dfs::new(&graph, a);
    while let Some(node_index) = dfs.next(&graph) {
        let mut neighbors = graph.neighbors(node_index).detach();
        while let Some((edge_idx, _)) = neighbors.next(&graph) {
            let edge_weight = &mut graph[edge_idx]; 
            if *edge_weight == 0 {
                *edge_weight = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again. But if I'm reading the second code block correctly, isn't the Dfs completely unfiltered? For my use case (I only gave very simplified code in the question) I need the Dfs to be filtered too. Which makes it trickier.

Comment: Yep, that's an unfiltered traversal. You might be able to implement an owning wrapper type `struct FilteredGraph(graph::Graph)` and implement `GraphRef + Visitable<NodeId = N, Map = VM>` for it such that you can use it in a `Dfs`. After the traversal you can move the graph out of the wrapper again. Although at that point your initial suggestion of collecting indices into a  `Vec<EdgeIndex>` could be preferable.